# SQL. Postgresql. Выборка по нескольким полям

Tags: sql, postgresql

Из базы нужно выбрать записи по 2 совмещенным полям. Совмещенная строка будет иметь вид - param1_param2, т.е 2 поля будут разделены символом "_". Такая строка у меня является уникальной в таблице.
У таблицы стоит ограничение целостности и индекс:

```
UNIQUE (column1, column2);
UNIQUE INDEX table_column1_column2_key ON table USING btree (column1, column2)
```

column1 и column2 являются integer полем.
Нужно организовать запрос так, чтобы можно было выбрать как по одному ключу, там и по нескольким (до 2-х тысяч).
Запрос вот такого типа получается слишком громоздким при большом количестве ключей, да и по скорости обработки не подходит

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1 = value1 AND column2 = value2) OR (column1 = value3 AND column2 = value4)
```

Comment: На вопрос я вроде ответил, но так и не понял, что вы хотели сказать, про значения, разделенные знаком подчеркивания. Вы хотите в запрос именно строкой вписать кучу значений с разделителем и что бы запрос уже из строки значения вытащил и получил по ним записи ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С объемом самого запроса бороться просто:

```
select * from table
 where (column1,column2) in( (1,2), (3,4), (5,6) )
```

На скорость это улучшение скорее всего не скажется. Он все равно будет много значений искать в индексе. Но 2к записей по индексу должны находится достаточно быстро. Если есть проблемы со скоростью надо смотреть план выполнения запроса. Что то мне подсказывает, что он у вас сложнее, чем просто `select *` ...

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения оптимизации лучше всего использовать JOIN со сгенерированной на лету табличкой:

```
SELECT *
FROM(VALUES
  (value1, value2),
  (value3, value4),
  (value5, value6)
)T(value1, value2)
 INNER JOIN table ON value1 = column1 AND value2 = column2
```

Индексы будут отлично использоваться.
А вот с OR будет всё намного печальнее.

**upd:** Если пар по которым будем искать около 2000, то лучше записать их во временную табличку, и только потом делать JOIN.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE param1||param2 in (value1||value2, value11||value22)
```

Comment: Хорошо бы еще добавить объяснение того что вы предлагаете

Comment: 1. Числовые значения сначала нужно привести к строке. 2. Ну, и '1'||'11'=='11'||'1'.

Comment: В условии было сказано что поля имеют тип строка. Зачем ее нужно приводить к строке?